# Exempting a cell containing a specific character

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

First, let me clarify that this is my first time doing anything with Google Apps Script or javascript in general. I'm trying to create a function that adds checkboxes to all cells in a column which is easy enough and I've already managed this.

I do, however, have a caveat:

- I press the button I've assigned my function to and it applies a checkbox to every cell in the desired row.
- I want to create an exception to this function for all cells containing a certain character (in this case, "¬".)

> ```
> function addLine () {
>
> SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RP Checklist")
>
>     .getRange('A5:A')
>     .insertCheckboxes();
> }
> ```

This is what I have so far. How would I go about creating the desired exempt cells?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear whether you want to insert checkboxes in column A only, or in multiple columns across rows that match your criteria.

Comment: Hi there! I'd like to only insert checkboxes into column A only.

Comment: Try the code in the answer below and comment back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to insert those checkboxes one by one, like this:

```
function insertCheckBoxesAllTheWayDownExceptWhenTheCellContainsTheNotSign() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('RP Checklist!A5:A');
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().flat();
  values.forEach((value, rowIndex) => {
    if (!value.includes('¬')) {
      range.offset(rowIndex, 0, 1, 1)
        .insertCheckboxes();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly. Thank you very much.